# windows service program in C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I need to write windows service program which is to run a function once in every hour. I am new to windows service programming. Can anyone guide me how to start this

Comment: 'running a function once in every hour' does not need a windows service. Please expand on why you think you need a windows service.

Comment: It is easy for my client to install in their machine.

Comment: The installation of services can also be non-trivial. I don't think this should be guiding the design of your app. It is an infrastructure concern. It's also possible to add the creation of scheduled tasks as part of the installation of an app. This would make your app much simpler, e.g. it could be a simple console app.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe instead of writing own service you can use Windows Scheduler to run you application every hour?

Comment: +1 @Mark Taylor: Given the information in your question, this is a perfectly valid answer and in the general case this is the easiest thing to do. If you need something more specific please add this to your question.

Comment: That's what I do most of the time, too. Avoiding Windows Services whenever possible is a very good decision in my opinion :-)

Comment: +1 for use Windows Scheduler! In my project also has wrote several windows batch files to run application , record log , and be controlled by Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 5):

See this MSDN article on services: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).
Here is the overview: [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx).

To run an operation every hour, use a timer.

Comment: How to write windows service program and install it ?

Comment: @Mark, how to install/uninstall is included as another link at the bottom of one of those pages: [How to: Install and Uninstall Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha.aspx)

Comment: @Dan, two links slapped together doesn't make a good answer even if they are technically correct. At least try to give a little context what they are about.

Comment: @Slugster +1 - it's also important that we validate a large assumption made in the question, i.e. that a service is required, before sending the OP off in this direction

Comment: I am not asking what is the best one from windows servive and shedular

Answer (score 1):

Hers is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) of a simple service. To have this service run a function every hour would just require the creation of a simple one second timer.